# Distinguish between expensive and inexpensive health checks

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We typically ping `/health` very frequently in our highly available applications to determine when failover needs to happen. Spring Boot Actuator works well for this if the health indicators that are used don't make expensive calls to external dependencies like a database or  web service. However, we like the ease of writing health indicators and how it plugs into the `/health` endpoint.

Is there any way to configure the Spring Boot Actuator such that only a subset of the indicators are executed in certain circumstances? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not caching your responses on your custom health indicators for a few calls. So that only every other or potentially every 5th or 10th check is actually executed.

Comment: @hrrgttnchml , There are still disadvantages to this approach. If the `/health` check calls are run very frequently (say every 5 seconds) than the calls are still expensive. Additionally I believe the caching is for the entire response and one would have to implement custom caching for particular health indicators.

Comment: Nope I don't mean caching the entire response but inside the health check itself. So that not every call does an expensive calculation.

Comment: @hrrgttnchml that's definitely a possibility. I was hoping one of the Spring Boot developers would chime in and understand their appetite for accepting this as a new feature (before creating an issue on their GitHub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control which health indicators are enabled using the `management.health.<service>.enabled` properties. For example, to switch off the database health check:

```
management.health.db.enabled: false
```

The full list of properties is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). At the time of writing they are:

```
management.health.db.enabled
management.health.diskspace.enabled
management.health.mongo.enabled
management.health.rabbit.enabled
management.health.redis.enabled
management.health.solr.enabled
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this but it unfortunately doesn't answer my question. I know I can disable certain health checks, but I don't want to disable them. I'd like to leave them enabled and I was curious if there was the possibility of conditionally checking them at run-time.

Comment: @Centinul No, Boot doesn't support anything like that at the moment. Feel free to open an issue and we'll consider it. I'm not convinced at the moment, though. Trying to only check a particular service conditionally feels like a premature optimisation that'll leave you in the dark about your app's actual health.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I've opened a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3441).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation right now. I just implemented a custom `Endpoint` which does the expensive health checks.

If you need the comfort of an HTTP endpoint you can also implement an `AbstractEndpointMvcAdapter` which does a similar HTTP status code mapping as Spring's `HealthMvcEndpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

**2021 Update**

**Health Groups** provide the exact functionality you're asking about.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.3/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health.groups

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot >= 2.2, you can use the separate library [spring-boot-async-health-indicator](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/spring-boot-async-health-indicator/) to make your expensive healthchecks run on a separate thread by simply annotating them with `@AsyncHealth`.

This will ensure that your `/health` endpoint always return very fast and does not wait on those expensive healthchecks to complete.

Example:

```
@AsyncHealth
@Component
public class MyExpensiveHealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        verySlowCheck(); // This method does not run when /health is called
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

*Disclaimer: I created this library for this exact purpose*